# WPF Calendar DisplayDate BUG

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, datepicker, controltemplate

Can anyone explain why the Calendar doesn't show correctly DisplayDate?

If I put the DatePicker outside the ContentControl it work perfectly, but somehow it doesn't work when it's wrapped by a ControlTemplate.

Any suggestion on how to force the Calender to show correctly DisplayDate?

```
<StackPanel>
    <ContentControl>
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <DatePicker DisplayDate="12/12/2011" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                        VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
    <DatePicker DisplayDate="12/12/2011" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I'm after trying it in both scenaria - I can't see the difference. What are you considering as bug?

Comment: Hi Dimitry. The bug is when you click on the Calendar popup. In the calendar screen the date 12/12/2011 should have a blue frame around it. That's the date I have set in the property DisplayDate. In this example only the SelectedDate has the blue frame around it. Which is wrong...